# How can i show the doctor Name in Laravel

Tags: laravel

i need some help to solve my problem .
I want to show the name of a doctor with the patient have an appointment with him. 
The patient will make an appointment with a doctor, and after when the patient gets connected he must see the list of his appointments.
I get the error : `syntax error, unexpected 'endforeach'`

This is the index.blade.php

```
     @if(Session::has('log_in'))
@foreach($getpatient as $getpat)
    @foreach ($patient as $gp)
     @foreach ($doc as $d)

       @if( $getpat->IDP == $gp->id) 
       @if( $getpat->IDD == $d->ID)
    <p> {{$gp->Nom}} {{$gp->Prénom}}  </p>
   <p>  {{$d->Nom}} {{$d->Prénom}} </p>

    @endif
@endforeach
@endforeach

  @endif
```

And this is the controller :

```
**  public function  index  () {
        $articles=blog::orderBy('created_at','desc')->paginate(3);
        $ville=Vil::orderBy('Ville','desc')->get();
        $specialité=spec::orderBy('id','desc')->get();
        $pati=patient::orderBy('id','desc')->get();
        $rdvvv=rendezvous::orderBy('id','desc')->get();
        $docdoc=doc::orderBy('id','desc')->get();

        return view ('index',[
              'sp'=>$specialité,
              'vi'=>$ville,
              'pub'=> $articles,
              'getpatient' => $rdvvv,
               'patient' =>$pati,
               'doc'=>$docdoc 
        ]);
}**
```

i'm new in laravel and i hope that you can help me 
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i forget to add @endif and @endforeach  , so it would be like this :

```
 @if(Session::has('log_in'))
     @foreach($getpatient as $getpat)
        @foreach ($patient as $gp)
           @foreach ($doc as $d)

           @if( $getpat->IDP == $gp->id) 
         @if( $getpat->IDD == $d->ID)
         <p> {{$gp->Nom}} {{$gp->Prénom}}  </p>
         <p>  {{$d->Nom}} {{$d->Prénom}} </p>
          @endif
        @endif
          @endforeach
      @endforeach
    @endforeach
 @endif
```